# How to check the actual image (quality) of a document scanner before buying it?

Tags: scanner

I want to buy a scanner. My old one stopped working and I bought another one 6 months ago but it makes the images lossy/pixelated.

But my problem is that I don't want to buy another scanner without knowing for sure that the quality is what I'm looking for.

But how can I know?
Is there a way to tell the picture quality?

Comment: I would suggest trying to read some reviews for scanners that you're interested in. The reviews might share images that have been scanned from that model so you can see the quality of the image, but you won't have the original paper they scanned for comparison. I would also consider the DPI of the scanner to be one of the most important specs to keep an eye on for sharpness and avoiding pixelation. "Lossyness" is usually a side-effect of scanning to JPEG and most scanners can do PNG or lossless image formats too.